# Selection of any PPT file globally Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have created a code which select a PPT file from my system. But this is a hard code. How can I create a global code instead of hardcoding?
My code is given below:

```
Sub PPTTest()
  Dim PPT As Object

  Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

  PPT.Presentations.Open "D:\Us\70\Desktop\Shaon\BOD.pptx", , , False

  ' Note that the file name and the module
  ' name are required to path the macro correctly.
  PPT.Run "BOD.pptx!Module1.KillSpecificSlide"

 End Sub
```

How to make this selection globally?

Comment: What do you mean with "global"?

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie it means I can choose any ppt file available in my system.Here in the code above my code name is BOD.pptx and its written in the code where as I want to create a code where I can choose any ppt file from my system

Answer (score 0):

The following is an (incompete) example taken from one of my Excel macros:

```
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = ""
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
Set fldr = Nothing
```

`sItem` now contains the selected item. Use it in your `PPT.Presentations.Open` call.

Note: this code still must be in an MS-Office file (word, ppt, excel). To make such a macro "global" it must be in the startup template.

You can find or change the Startup location containing startup templates (in excel, but probably too in ppt) under Excel Options, Trust Center, Trust Center Settings.

Comment: This code works fine to choose the path name...After execution I got  D:\Us\70\Desktop\Shaon\BOD.pptx...Now from this path if I just want to store only BOD.pptx in a variable and not the total path then how to do it?

Comment: Use `Mid()`. But I strongly suggest you learn more about VB and read through the available functions and methods. There are more functions like Mid that can help you.